# Output Pulumi Resource Data in Python

Tags: python, pulumi

I am having trouble figuring out how to output property information in Pulumi for resources. For instance, I deploy a resource via inline python, and Pulumi cloud shows the resources along with all the various properties (name and values), but I can't figure out how to access these further along in my code. This seems like its overly complicated in Pulumi. For instance, if I have the following:

```
import foo

some_project = "foo"
stack_name = auto.fully_qualified_stack_name("foo", project_name, "dev")

program = Foo()

stack = auto.create_or_select_stack(stack_name=stack_name, project_name=project_name, program=program.bar)

#Get ID of bar and print it
print(program.bar.id)
```

But this output results in:

```
To get the value of an Output[T] as an Output[str] consider:
 1. o.apply(lambda v: f"prefix{v}suffix")
```

However, even when attempting to do this using apply, I get not output. I feel there should be a much easier way to simply grab a property value of a resource I have created and use it as input for my code.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is how Pulumi currently works. It's almost like dealing with promises in JavaScript where you would need `.then()` to get your async results. So as your application grows the `apply()` nesting can sometimes get confusing.

That said, `apply` should still work if used properly. For example to print the property of a resource after it's available:

```py
my_api.id.apply(lambda id: print(f'My ID: {id}'))
```

Note that the print output would show up under the `Diagnostics:` section in stdout. And it's order might not be what you expect because pulumi can decide when to execute it. For example, the output of the code below

```py
print('start')
my_api.id.apply(lambda id: print(f'My ID: {id}'))
print('end')
```

might be

```bash
start
end
My ID: mja1bcjigf
```